# How to get CSJ files for blackberry playbook signing?

Tags: android, blackberry, code-signing, blackberry-playbook

I want to port an application from  android to Blackberry playbook. For that I Register in This link http://developer.blackberry.com/android/signingkey and I get 3 **CSI** files named `client-RBB-3973888918,client-RCR-3973888918,client-RRT-3973888918`. But for Registering I need 2 csj files (RDK and PBDT files). How I get these files. Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't Know what happend first time. I register again in the same link. Then i got the 2 csj files (RDK and PBDT files).

Answer (score 0):

CSI files are used to providing the signing with Blackberry smartphones, may be it is possible once you register first time you chose only For blackberry smartphone. CSJ files are used in signing purposes for Tablet . So you will get these two CSJ files if you choose signing for Tablet OS. 
For your info 
http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/20779/Obtain_and_install_signing_keys_1264848_11.jsp

Or

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/BlackBerry-Applications-and-code-signing-Start-to-Finish/ta-p/445848